# What is wrong with my deformation gradient calculation?

Tags: transformations

I created two ellipses,
$\hspace{150px}$[image],
where the red ellipsis is as the blue one, except translated to the right and rotated by ${30}^{\circ} .$ Using rotation matrix,

$$
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    x  \\[2px]
    y   \end{array}
\right]
\
\phantom{F} ~=~
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    cos(30^{\circ})  & -sin(30^{\circ})  \\[2px]
    sin(30^{\circ}) & \phantom{}cos(30^{\circ})
  \end{array}
\right]
\
*
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    X  \\[2px]
    Y   \end{array}
\right]
\
$$

Next I tried to calculate deformation gradient by using principal axes(a and b for initial ellipsis,c and d for translated one), and then I decomposed $\vec{c}$ and $\vec{d}$ vectors,$$
\begin{alignat}{7}
\vec{c} &~~=~~ 1.0021 \, \vec{b} &~&+ &~&0.8654 \, \vec{a} \\[5px]
\vec{d} &~~=~~ 0.8654 \, \vec{b} &&- &&0.2505 \, \vec{a}
\end{alignat}
$$and created the deformation gradient as$$
F ~=~
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \phantom{-} 0.8654  &    1.0021  \\[2px]
             -  0.2505  &    0.8654
  \end{array}
\right]
\,.
$$But it is obvious that, this is not the same as the ${30}^{\circ}$ rotation matrix that I had expected it to be,$$
\phantom{F} {\llap{\textsf{rotation matrix}}} ~=~
\left[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    0.8660  &            -  0.5000  \\[2px]
    0.5000  &   \phantom{-} 0.8660
  \end{array}
\right]
\,.
$$

**Question:**  Why aren't the deformation gradient, $F ,$ and and the rotation matrix, $\textsf{rotation matrix} ,$ the same?

Comment: I'm not sure your rotation matrix is correct, usually the sin/cos are swapped in the second row    e.g  [ cos -sin ] [ sin cos ]

Comment: @PaulHK, silly mistake while writing it,i rewrite it, now its in the correct form.

Comment: The c and d vectors do not look correct in the diagram. They should be equivalent to a and b but rotated. How are you finding those vectors? Maybe there's a bug there.

Comment: @NathanReed isnt them correct ? There is an small error margin, but compared to difference between rotation matrix and F, its nothing.

Comment: I don't think it's a small error margin. The component of c along b, and the component of d along a, are both off by about a factor of 2. The vectors as shown in the diagram are plainly quite a bit off from the true axes of the red ellipse.